# Merge two columns with unequal number of expressions into one column and get unique value

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns in two tables. I need to merge these two columns into one, while making sure all the values in the resulting column are unique. Something like this:

```
Alice   Alice
Andy    NULL
Bob     Bob
Carl    NULL
Jack    Jack
Joan    NULL
Kai     NULL
Mary    Mary
NULL    Mo
Tony    NULL
NULL    Trick
Judy

Alice
Andy
Bob
Carl
Jack    
Joan    
Kai     
Mary    
Mo      
Tony
Trick
Judy
```

I can't use UNION because these columns might not always have the same number of expressions and it returns an error like the following. What should I do? Or is it possible to do so?

```
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
```

Comment: You can use the UNION if you just look at these two columns in a CTE or subquery, then join it back to your main query.

Comment: actually you can use a UNION.   You must have been doing it incorrectly.   Post your UNION query and we will be able to tell you what it was you did wrong.

Comment: Do you have 2 columns with same name in a table?

Comment: How is it that the 2 columns don't have the same number of values (expressions?). Is it 1 table or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Given your data (where the values are the same in the two columns if they are both there), then:

```
select distinct coalesce(a, b)
from table t;
```

If that condition doesn't hold, then you need a `union`, which Giorgi's answer explains.

Answer (score 0):

If, I understand your question, then you can use CASE Statement for both column

```
create table tempcombine(
a varchar(20)
)

create table tempcombine1(
b varchar(20)
)

--truncate table tempcombine
insert into tempcombine values ('Alice')
insert into tempcombine values ('Andy')
insert into tempcombine values ('Bob')
insert into tempcombine values ('Carl')
insert into tempcombine values (NULL)
insert into tempcombine values ('Judy')


insert into tempcombine1 values ('Alice')
insert into tempcombine1 values (NULL)
insert into tempcombine1 values ('Bob')
insert into tempcombine1 values (NULL)
insert into tempcombine1 values ('Trick')
```

Then you can use CASE to get desired result

```
SELECT *FROM 
(
 Select distinct
 Case when a = b then a
     When a IS NULL then b
     When b IS null then a end UniqueColumnName
From tempcombine, tempcombine1) as ab 
where ab.UniqueColumnName is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. That should work. I just hope there is a better and more efficient way to do it. This will be painful if the columns are large.

Comment: at that case you should re-view your DB tables (which contains this data) and add some PK and FK

Answer (score 0):

Simple `UNION`:

```
declare @t1 table(Alice varchar(10))
declare @t2 table(Alice varchar(10))


insert into @t1 values
('Alice'),
('Andy'),
('Bob'),
('Carl'),
('Jack'),
('Joan'),
('Kai'),
('Mary'),
(NULL),
('Tony'),
(NULL),
('Judy')


insert into @t2 values
('Alice'),
(NULL),
('Bob'),
(NULL),
('Jack'),
(NULL),
(NULL),
('Mary'),
('Mo'),
(NULL),
('Trick')


select Alice from @t1 where Alice is not null
union
select Alice from @t2 where Alice is not null
```

Output:

```
Alice
Andy
Bob
Carl
Jack
Joan
Judy
Kai
Mary
Mo
Tony
Trick
```